# GSI-GMS image bootloop, non-GMS works fine

Tags: rom-flashing, boot-loop, aosp, vanilla-android

Flashing the ARM64 version (Android 11 or 12) from [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/generic-system-image/releases) works fine on my Blackview BL6000 Pro.
However, flashing any ARM64+GMS only boots into the bootloader (not fastbootd).

In general, how would one investigate why this happens?

I can boot into the Stock Recovery, however, I cannot `adb` into the device because it shows up as `unauthorized` (perfectly authorized in the OS though).
Unfortunately, afaik there's also no custom recovery available for my device.

I thought about reading `logcat` or `dmesg` but I don't see a way to access them without having
`adb` access.

Thanks for any hints.

Here's my procedure:

1. SP Flash the stock rom
2. Unlock the bootloader in the dev options
3. `adb reboot bootloader`
4. `fastboot flashing unlock`
5. `fastboot reboot fastboot`
6. `fastboot delete-logical-partition product`(this is necessary because the GSI is larger than the stock rom `system` partition)
7. `fastboot erase system`
8. `fastboot flash system aosp-system.img` (automatically resizes `system`)
9. `fastboot -w`
10. `fastboot reboot` which lands me in the OS for the non-GMS version, and in the bootloader for the GMS version.

Comment: I didn't figure out this issue but I ended up using CAOS11 https://github.com/eremitein/treble-patches/wiki/CAOS11-Project.